# How can I view cards from multiple boards simultaneously?

Tags: trello, trello-boards

I've seen similar questions to this but I want to articulate that my request is to view multiple boards at the same time.

This would be a common requirement for a product owner or manager who needs to see multiple workflows.

Comment: Your wording is not clear on what you are looking for.  There is no "All Cards / All People" option as far as I know.

Comment: I guess it's not possible on Trello. You can do that in Asana, though.

Answer (score 1):

Select "Cards" from the menu under your name (top right of a Trello page)

This will show you all cards across all boards you are assigned to.

Select another profile to see the cards where that person is assigned too.

Answer (score 1):

I have released an Open Source project on Github for exactly this use case: https://github.com/natterstefan/react-trello-multiboard.

React-Trello-Multiboard is a single-page application built with React displaying multiple cards of several Trello boards and lists. The cards and lists can be filtered by preferred team members and/or "sprints" (or weeks, however you call it). Visit the GitHub page for more details and a list of features.

You can find a live example here: https://multiboardfortrello.com/.